# Git Sub Modules vs Private Sources for Package Managers

Tags: git, npm, pip, git-submodules

What are the advantages of using a local package manager (e.g pip or npm) than using git sub-modules ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git` is a **development** tool; you use it during development but not deployment. `pip` is a deployment tool; during development you use it to install necessary libraries; during deployment your users use it to install your package with dependencies.

Use submodules when you need something from a remote repository in your **development** environment. For example, if said remote repository contains Makefile(s) or other non-python files that you need and that usually aren't installed with `pip`.