# What are the main advantages of using git submodules over package managers like npm?

Tags: git, npm, git-submodules

My current understanding of git submodules is that it allows one to track multiple repos as dependencies.

It's better than pasting code in because it can track upstream changes and will allow one to easily update them.

It's better than manually cloning repos into a dependencies folder since submodules will let you view all changes and update them all at once easily. It would require committing all the dependency code as part of the parent project. Other collaborators would be forced to pull the same versions of the dependencies since the code is committed with rest of the project.

However, I don't understand its advantages over a package manager like npm. Atlassian claims "package managers have the downside of requiring installation and version management at all places the origin code is deployed." Why is this a downside and how does git submodules escape this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Let's me paraphrase [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59686222/7976758) to a very similar question.

`git` is a **development** tool; you use it during development but not deployment. `npm` is a deployment tool; during development you use it to install necessary libraries; during deployment your users use it to install your package with dependencies.

Use submodules when you need something from a remote repository in your **development** environment. For example, if said remote repository contains Makefile(s) or other files that you need and that usually aren't installed with `npm`.